# PL/SQL check date is valid

Tags: oracle, validation, date, plsql

If I have a date format `DDMM` in PL/SQL and I want to validate it. What is the correct way to do it?

`DD` is the day and `MM` is the moth.

```
For an example:
0208 - is a valid date
3209 - is not a valid date
0113 - is not a valid date.
```

Comment: is `'2902'` a valid date?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write a function like this one, for instance:

```
create or replace function is_valid(p_val in varchar2)
return number
is
  not_a_valid_day   exception;
  not_a_valid_month exception;
  pragma exception_init(not_a_valid_day, -1847);
  pragma exception_init(not_a_valid_month, -1843);
  l_date date;
begin
  l_date := to_date(p_val, 'ddmm');
  return 1;
exception
  when not_a_valid_day or not_a_valid_month
  then return 0;
end;



SQL> with test_dates(dt) as(
  2    select '0208' from dual union all
  3    select '3209' from dual union all
  4    select '0113' from dual
  5  )
  6  select dt, is_valid(dt) as valid
  7    from test_dates
  8  /

DT        VALID
---- ----------
0208          1
3209          0
0113          0
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that `to_date(p_val, 'ddmm')` defaults to the current year; which doesn't matter of course, unless `p_val` is `2902`, which is invalid this year but was valid last year. OP needs to decide how to handle that case anyway.

Comment: It was more an observation for the OP, as only they can know the context - but e.g. if they want `2902` to always be valid they could use a fixed year, if it's a moving window then its potentially a problem. Just something they need to be aware of, not a criticism of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

-- If you have oracle 12c

```
with test_dates(dt) as(
select '0208' from dual union all
select '3209' from dual union all
select '0113' from dual)

select dt, validate_conversion(dt as date, 'DDMM') as valid from test_dates

DT        VALID
---- ----------
0208          1
3209          0
0113          0
```

Answer (score 0):

`to_date` raises an exception if its input parameter is not a valid date. So you can do something like:

```
declare
  x date;
begin
  x := to_date('3210', 'DDMM'); -- Will raise ORA-1847
  x := to_date('0113', 'DDMM'); -- Will raise ORA-1843
exception
  when others then 
    if sqlcode in (-1843, -1847) then
      dbms_output.put_line('Invalid Date!');
      null;
    else
      raise;
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: See @NicholasKrasnov's answer for a better version!