# Given Date valid in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to verify valid date for all the formats

I am getting this error.

My input is IDateFormat = 'MM/YY/DD' and IStringDate = '2001-01-01'

I am getting the below error.

ORA-01843: not a valid month

ORA-06512: at "NECHO_APP.CONVERTTODATE" ORA-06512: at line 10 2011-01-01 Process exited.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE convertToDate
                (IDateFormat        Varchar2,
                IStringDate     Varchar2,
              OConvertedDate    out timestamp,
                  OError OUT            Int )

AS

  TDateFormat       Varchar2(20);
  TStringDate       Varchar2(20);

BEGIN

OError  := 0;
TDateFormat := LTrim(RTrim(IDateFormat));
TStringDate  := LTrim(RTrim(IStringDate));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TStringDate);
IF IS_VALID(TStringDate,'yyyy-mm-dd') = 1 THEN

        SELECT TO_DATE(TStringDate,TDateFormat) INTO OConvertedDate FROM DUAL;
           OError := 0;
 END IF;

END;

 - FUNCTION:

    create or replace function is_valid(p_val in varchar2, fmt varchar2)
    return number
    is

      not_a_valid_day   exception;
      not_a_valid_month exception;
      pragma exception_init(not_a_valid_day, -1847);
      pragma exception_init(not_a_valid_month, -1843);
      l_date date;
    begin
      l_date := to_date(p_val, fmt);

      return 1;
    exception
      when not_a_valid_day or not_a_valid_month
      then return 0;
    end is_valid;
```

Comment: You are confused between the input parameter and function of to_date function. I suggest you to go through some example of to_date.

Comment: I came up with solution, which was accepted in Stack over flow.       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524448/pl-sql-check-date-is-valid

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your is_valid function. I am talking about to_date function. TO_DATE function is use to convert an string to date. it does not convert a date from one form to another

Comment: Unbelevable how many times dates are stored as string value instead of proper date format!

Answer (score 1):

You should use this

```
 SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TStringDate,'YYYY-MM-DD'),TDateFormat) INTO OConvertedDate FROM DUAL;
```

However, you should go through the usage of to_date and to_char.

Comment: The above option also not working